# nginx не видит webpack dev сервер

Tags: vue.js, nginx, webpack

Есть сервер nginx на 80 порту(testsite) и есть webpack dev сервер на 81 порту(test_vue), там vue приложение. Сделал проксирование, но когда перехожу на testsite/test_vue в консоль падает https://testsite/js/app.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found). Подскажите пожалуйста, где мой косяк.

```
//sites-availeble/testsite.conf  
    location /vue_test/ {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8081/;
        proxy_redirect off;
        client_max_body_size 4m;
    }
    location /dist/ {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8081/dist/;
        proxy_redirect off;
        client_max_body_size 4m;
    }
```

```
//vue.config.js  
module.exports = {
  devServer: {
    disableHostCheck: true
  }
}
```

Comment: А где у вас правило для /js?

Comment: Я не могу использовать локейшн /js/, тк у testsite есть своя директория js, со своими js и при обращении к ней он будет искать файлы на localhost:8081/js. Мне кажется, что тут нужно смотреть в сторону конфигов вебпака.

Comment: `Мне кажется, что тут нужно смотреть в сторону конфигов вебпака`. Ноу. Адрес `/js` Nginx просто не будет обрабатывать. Вообще у вас все как-то запутано, не могу понять, куда, что отправляется.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`/vue_test/` начало урла проксируется в тестовый сервер?
А webpack часто генерирует пути к либам с абсолютными путями.

Установите в тестовый конфиг baseUrl/publicPath https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#publicpath

```
module.exports = {
  publicPath: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'
    ? '/'
    : '/vue_test/'
}
```

Уберите `/` в конце прокси для того чтоб прилетал полный путь на сервер.

Comment: Спасибо, работает)

Answer (score 0):

Не знаю, что именно у вас не так, ибо нужно смотреть полную конфигурацию и nginx, и webpack, но у меня всё работает без особых хитростей только на nginx, не затрагивая ничего другого.

Конфиг прокси сервера такой:

```
server {
  listen 8100;
  location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8080/;
    # Установка обычных прокси-хедеров
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    # Установка хедеров для нормального проксирования WebSocket
    # Это необходимо, так как горячая перезагрузка webpack на этом и работает
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
  }
}
```

Возможно, у вас проблема именно в отсутствии хедеров. Про проксирование WebSocket можете ознакомиться в [официальных доках](https://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/websocket.html).